# How to verify $T(f)=df/dt(=du/dt\ +\ i\ dv/dt)$ for $T:\ V\rightarrow V$ is a complex linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the vector space of differentiable functions $f:{R}\rightarrow C$. Define $T:\ V\rightarrow V$ by $T(f)=df/dt(=du/dt\ +\ i\ dv/dt)$. How to prove it's complex linear transformation?

$T(af)=a (df/dt)=a(du/dt)+ai\ (dv/dt)=aT(f)$

$T(f+g)=d(f+g)/dt=df/dt+dg/dt=T(f)+T(g)$

I am not sure if my procedure is correct. Could someone check?

Comment: You already start with $T(af) = a(df/dt)$, the claim you want to prove. So that's not a proper proof. Use the definition of derivative. It is basically the as in the real case.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about $f=u+iv$ and use the "direct" definition
$$f'(t):=\lim_{h\to 0}{f(t+h)-f(t)\over h}\in{\mathbb C}$$
instead. It is then obvious that $T$ is ${\mathbb C}$-linear. But there is another point: This $T$ cannot be considered as a map $T:\>V\to V$, as $\>Tf\>$ need not be differentiable anymore. Take the example $f(t):=|t|^{3/2}$.

Comment: Probably it is just a ypo and $V$ is the space of complex differentiable functions